# Retrieve all Microsoft Windows updates

Tags: windows, updates, wsus

Is there any way to get information about all Microsoft updates including non-security Critical Updates? I know this can be done with WSUS but I can't use WSUS in my company. I also tried to use WUA API to get the list of updates, however it gives only updates that are applicable to the running machine. What I want is a complete list that is similar to what we have in WSUS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the Windows updates have a look onto the [WSUS Offline Update](http://www.wsusoffline.net/) project. It allows you to download all updates (don't know if only security updates or all) of selected Microsoft products and it offers a way to apply those updates using a local batch file.

Comment: It is a great tool but it gives only security updates that come from wsusscn2.cab

Comment: For those people who are able to understand German there is http://patch-info.de which lists also optional updates.